# How to covert "IPictureDisp" to "IPicture"

Tags: visual-c++, atl, ole

I am using VC++.

`IPicture` provide multiple functions, such as `get_Handle`, `Render` and `SaveAsFile`. It is easy to be used.

`IPictureDisp` inherits from `IDispatch`, so it only provide `invoke` method. It is not friendly.

Now I get one `ocx` which only returns `IPictureDisp` object. So is there a method to convert `IPictureDisp` to `IPicture` directly? I have not much experience in `ATL/COM`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MSDN states:

> OLE Implementation
>
> [...] the system provides a standard implementation of the picture object. Its primary interfaces are IPicture and IPictureDisp. A picture object is created with OleCreatePictureIndirect and supports both the IPicture and the IPictureDisp interfaces.

With both interfaces supported, having `IPictureDisp` you can query for `IPicture` via regular `QueryInterface`:

```
IPictureDisp* pPictureDisp = ...
CComQIPtr<IPicture> pPicture = pPictureDisp;
```

Note that if it does not work, and `IPicture` is not directly available, you can use `IPictureDisp::Invoke` with `DISPID_PICT_HANDLE`, `DISPID_PICT_RENDER` to access the properties/methods.